# Nginx: Serving robots.txt using an alias

Tags: nginx

I've just started playing with nginx + uwsgi, and I'm trying to figure out how to serve a robots.txt using an alias. The following is my current configuration which is not working:

```
http {
    server {

        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;
        }

        location /static {
            root /Users/dave/PycharmProjects/nginx_test/static;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            alias /Users/dave/PycharmProjects/nginx_test/static/robots.txt;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, my simple test app is a Flask app which should use Flask routing to serve request against `/*`, and nginx should serve static files under `/static/*`, but of course robots.txt should be accessible via `/robots.txt`.
Why I'm not able to access to `/robots.txt` directly while `/static/robots.txt` works as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly is the `robots.txt` file? If it is in `/Users/dave/PycharmProjects/nginx_test/static/robots.txt` then both your `root` directive and `alias` directives are wrong.

The correct `root` directive for locations beginning with `/static/...` is:

```
location /static {
    root /Users/dave/PycharmProjects/nginx_test;
}
```

As the URI is appended to the document root to make the full path name.

In the case of `location = /robots.txt`, an alias is not required, only the addition of the last directory element to form the correct path name:

```
location = /robots.txt {
    root /Users/dave/PycharmProjects/nginx_test/static;
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more information.

Comment: yep, robots.txt is in /Users/dave/PycharmProjects/nginx_test/static/robots.txt, but by using your suggested settings I get an internal server error (500) for /robots.txt